# Send Email to Distribution List(DL) using Utility.SendMail Function?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

How to send email to Distribution List(DL) using Utility.SendMail Function?

I am using SharePoint Online and Want to do using CSOM.

Comment: AFAIK you can't, if you convert it to a mail enabled security group you should be able to.